# "Node: Created day" mismatched, not reflecting the actual created day

Tags: 7, views

Views Version: 7.x-3.0-alpha1

I was trying to create a blog archive view, like blog/yyyy/mm/dd, where blog/2011/03/10 is  supposed to display all posts created on 2011, March 10th. However, the page **blog/2011/03/10** actually displays all posts created on **2011, March, 11th**, one day advanced to the supplied day argument.

How to reproduce the bug:

1. clean install, enable modules.
2. create blog content type, generate dummy contents.
3. create a view:

   ```
     * Arguments:
           o Node: Created year
           o Node: Created month
           o Node: Created day

     * Path: blog

     * Filters
           o Node: Published Yes
           o Node: Type = blog
   ```

The year, month arguments show correctly, **just the day is wrong, always one day prior to the day argument.**

Can anyone point me to what went wrong?

Comment: This sounds like a datetime issue relating to the timezone setting of the site.

Comment: just update that the latest 7.x-3.0-beta3 fixed this bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually had this bug, but with views 2 on drupal 6, and instead of going forward a day, our view was going backward a day.

Have you tried updating to --dev to see if the issue still exists? I know a lot of patches have been committed since that alpha was released.

Comment: It is probably a bug mentioned and patched here: Incorrect timezone handling in views_date_sql_field()
http://drupal.org/node/1091698